# how to store value in second variable inside dropdown list

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

i have a website that is written in PHP and MYSQL with ajax that includes 3 dependent  drodpdown list  where the first dropdown conatins several values that are necessary for the 2 other dorpdown list.

what i need is to also be able to store one of these values in a second variable in order to use it  alone in other query.

[take a look on the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jxkh1.png)

## code

```
<?php

            // code for submit button action
            global $wpdb, $site_name, $data;
        //variables that handle the retrieved data from mysql database based on the ID of the variable in HTML (select)



        if(isset($_POST['query_submit']))
        {


           if(isset($_POST['site_name'])) 
              { 
               $site_name=$_POST['site_name'];

              }
              else { $site_name=""; }
    var_dump($site_name);
```

/* the above lines are added
      the var_dump display 3 values inside $site_name variable is there a way to trim or extract the third value before the SQL query down.
 */

```
$sql = $wpdb->prepare("select i.siteID
             , i.siteNAME
             , i.equipmentTYPE
             , c.latitude
             , c.longitude
             , c.height 
             , o.ownerNAME
             , o.ownerCONTACT
             , x.companyNAME
             , y.subcontractorCOMPANY
             , y.subcontractorNAME
             , y.subcontractorCONTACT
          from site_info i
          LEFT  
          JOIN owner_info o
            on i.ownerID = o.ownerID
          LEFT  
          JOIN company_info x
            on i.companyID = x.companyID
          LEFT 
          JOIN subcontractor_info y
            on i.subcontractorID = y.subcontractorID
            LEFT JOIN site_coordinates2 c
            on i.siteID=c.siteID 
            where 
            i.siteNAME = %s
            AND 
            o.ownerNAME = %s
            AND 
            x.companyNAME = %s
           ",$site_name,$owner_name,$company_name);

         $query_submit =$wpdb->get_results($sql, OBJECT);
```

## code

```
  <td><select id="site_name"  name = "site_name">
  <option value="">Select Site</option>
<?php
 $query_site_name =$wpdb->get_results("select DISTINCT 
    i.siteNAME, 
    i.ownerID, 
    i.companyID,
    o.ownerNAME,
    x.companyNAME
   from site_info i
   LEFT  
   JOIN owner_info o
   on i.ownerID = o.ownerID
   LEFT  
   JOIN company_info x
   on i.companyID = x.companyID
   ");

  foreach($query_site_name as $row)
  {   
     //$result1 = $row->ownerID;
    // $result2 = $row->companyID;  
    echo "<option value = '".$row ->ownerID.",".$row ->companyID.",".$row ->siteNAME."'>".$row->siteNAME."</option>";
   // echo "<option value = '".$row ->siteNAME."'>".$row->siteNAME."</option>";         
  } 
?>
</select></td>
```

## ajax code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

// make Dropdownlist depend on each other
$(document).ready(function(){


 // depend owner name on site name  

   $('#site_name').change(function(){
     var arrayId = $(this).val().split(",");
     if(arrayId != ""){
       var ownerID = arrayId[0];    //0
       var companyID = arrayId[1];  //1

     $.ajax({
      url:"<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/dropdown_fetch_owner.php",
       method:"POST",
       data:{ownerID:ownerID,companyID:companyID},
       dataType:"text",
       success:function(data){
                 var Response = data.split("--");
                 $('#owner_name').html(Response[2]);
                 $('#Company_name').html(Response[4]);
        }
     });


   }


  });


});

</script>
```

## dropdown_fetch_owner.php

```
<?php

 include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wordpress/wp-load.php');
 global $wpdb,$owner_name,$company_name;

   $sql =$wpdb->get_results("select ownerID, ownerNAME from owner_info where ownerID = '".$_POST['ownerID']."' ORDER BY ownerNAME");
   $owner_name = '--Owner--';
   var_dump($sql);
  foreach($sql as $row){


      $owner_name.= "<option value ='".$row ->ownerID."'>".$row->ownerNAME."</option>";
  }
  echo $owner_name;


   $sql =$wpdb->get_results("select companyID, companyNAME from company_info where companyID = '".$_POST['companyID']."' ORDER BY companyNAME");
   $company_name = '--Company--';
   var_dump($sql);


   foreach($sql as $row){

     $company_name.= "<option value ='".$row ->companyID."'>".$row->companyNAME."</option>";
   }
   echo $company_name;
   exit();




?>
```

Comment: You need to store that second information after selecting an option from the first dropdown list ?

Comment: @HamzaAbdaoui i need to store the **siteNAME** value  in a seperate variable or store the other 2 values in a separate variable in order to be able to use just siteNAME in a second query  .. i will edit my question and add some code take a  look

Comment: isn't `var arrayId = $(this).val().split(","); if(arrayId != ""){ var ownerID = arrayId[0];    //0 var companyID = arrayId[1];  //1` doing the job ?

Comment: yes i does whene i use the dropdown list ...but when i press the search button as you see in the first query it will  select and display the 3 values   ...if you see the image in the link the variable siteNAME handle 3 values where i need the third one only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this :

In your **PHP** script, you can `explode` the siteName into an `array`. [PHP explode() documentation](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.explode.php)

```
if(isset($_POST['site_name'])) 
   { 
       $site_name=$_POST['site_name'];
       $values = explode(",", $site_name);
       $site_name = $values[0]; //Or whatever cell you want
   }
 else { $site_name=""; }
```

**E D I T :**

As I sed before :

***In the PHP, Change this :***

```
echo "<option value = '".$row ->ownerID.",".$row ->companyID.",".$row ->siteNAME."'>".$row->siteNAME."</option>";
```

***To :***

```
echo "<option id = '".$row ->ownerID."' name = '".$row ->companyID."' value = '".$row ->siteNAME."'>".$row->siteNAME."</option>";
```

And ***In the ajax, change this :***

```
$('#site_name').change(function(){
 var arrayId = $(this).val().split(",");
 if(arrayId != ""){
   var ownerID = arrayId[0];    //0
   var companyID = arrayId[1];  //1
```

***To :***

```
$('#site_name').change(function(){
   var ownerID = $(this).children(":selected").attr("id");
   var companyID = $(this).children(":selected").attr("name");
```

Using this code, you wont need the code that i provided before the edit, you'll need to

**Change this :**

```
if(isset($_POST['site_name'])) 
   { 
       $site_name=$_POST['site_name'];
       $values = explode(",", $site_name);
       $site_name = $values[0]; //Or whatever cell you want
   }
 else { $site_name=""; }
```

**To :**

```
if(isset($_POST['site_name'])) 
   { 
       $site_name=$_POST['site_name']; //It'll contain just what you want ;)
   }
 else { $site_name=""; }
```

Comment: this will not solve the problem i don't know if i did not explain my problem in a write way i will edit the question   take a look

Comment: @Dany 7elo, I hope that i finally understood your need!

Comment: take look on the link in my question  i will display the result of your answer

Comment: In my answer, I used an array `$values`, this array will contain the 3 values that you have like this `|185|3|Amioun|`. So if you need to get _**185**_, you do `$values[0]` and so on ...

Comment: no i got the value that i need but it seams to having other problem because in the parameters field in debug mode it still select 3 values   hope that you did understand my comment and thank you for your help

Comment: You get that because in the first `select` (site Name) you have `<option value='185,3,Amioun'>Amioun</option>` and when you submit the form, it'll take the content of the `value` attribut, wich is _185,3,Amioun_. So are you looking for a solution that sends only "Amioun" instead of "185,3,Amioun" ?

Comment: these  2 values **185,3** are needed to do the process of ajax code for the 3 dropdown list.

but for the first SQL query i just need to send  **Amioun**  to become in the params field in the image ... site_name:"Amioun"

Comment: Should I remove the **Edit** ?!

Comment: No the edit answer was more comfortable to my question thank you  .. it give me what i want

Answer (score -1):

$('#owner_name').html(data[0].model_no);
use like this model_no is database field name use.

Comment: I DID NOT UNDERSTAND YOUR ANSWER

Comment: <option value ='".$row ->companyID."'>".$row->companyNAME."</option>" i not get any value in option tag using this i try it to in my code